# XSL - transformation of complex type

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to write a generic XSLT which should transform a very complex xml file. the xml file has many elements with complex type where some of them are repeatable. . In this simplified example the root element “data” has two complex elements (“info” and “contact”) 
I have copied a simplified example:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MyList.xslt"?>
      <data>

            <Info>
                <reportInfo>
                    <reportId>
                        <Number>1</Number>
                    </reportId>
                    <reportType>
                        <code>7</code>
                        <text>Main</text>
                    </reportType>
                    <product>
                        <code>3</code>
                        <text>myProduct</text>
                    </product>
                    <change>
                    <code>0</code>
                    </change>
                    <language>EN</language>
                    <Date>2013-09-25</Date>
                </reportInfo>
                <requestInfo>
            <customerReference>sample_Reference</customerReference>
                    <requestType>
                        <code>53</code>
                        <text>Onlineanfrage</text>
                    </requestType>
                    <Address>
                      <postBox>
                        <postBoxNumber>1</postBoxNumber>
                        <postalCode>123</postalCode>
                        <city>abcd</city>
                      </postBox>
                      <postBox>
                        <postBoxNumber>2</postBoxNumber>
                        <postalCode>456</postalCode>
                        <city>efgh</city>
                      </postBox>
                    </Address>
                </requestInfo>
            </Info>
            <contact>
               <Address>
                    <name>
                        <fullname>firstname surename</fullname>
                    </name>
                    <post>
                        <street>mystreet</street>
                        <postalCode>9876</postalCode>
                        <city>mycity</city>
                        <country>
                            <code>110</code>
                            <text>mycountry</text>
                        </country>
                    </post>
                    <othercontacts type="PHONE">123456</othercontacts>
                    <othercontacts type="FAX">123457</othercontacts>
                    <othercontacts type="EMAIL">email@email.com</othercontacts>
                </Address>
            </contact>

      </data>
```

I am looking for following outcome (tried to give an sample) where 
- (**text1**) is always the name() of first complex element under the root element (e.g. contact)
-( **text2**) is always parent of actual node (e.g. post)
- (**text3**) is name() of actual node (e.g. street / postalCode)
- (**Value**) is value-of text3 / actual node (e.g. mystreet / 9876). 
However, in some nodes (e.g. **othercontacts** within “**contact**”) the requirements is that 
- (**text1**) is always the name() of first complex element under the root element (e.g. contact)
-( **text2**) is always actual node (e.g. othercontract)
- (**text3**) should be “type”  (e.g. PHONE)
- (**Value**) is value-of “othercontract” (e.g. 123456)

```
    <MyList>
    <list>
    <text1>info</text1>
    <text2>reportId</text2>
    <text3>Number</text3>
    <Value>1</Value>
</list>
<list>
    <text1>info</text1>
    <text2>reportType</text2>
    <text3>code</text3>
    <Value>7</Value>
</list>
<list>
    <text1>info</text1>
    <text2>reportType</text2>
    <text3>text</text3>
    <Value>Main</Value>
</list>
..........
...........
    <list>
    <text1>info</text1>
    <text2>postBox</text2>
    <text3>postBoxNumber</text3>
    <Value>1</Value>
</list> 
<list>
    <text1>info</text1>
    <text2>postBox</text2>
    <text3>postalCode</text3>
    <Value>123</Value>
</list>
<list>
    <text1>info</text1>
    <text2>postBox</text2>
    <text3>city</text3>
    <Value>abcd</Value>
</list>
......
.......

<list>
    <text1>contact</text1>
    <text2>name</text2>
    <text3>fullname</text3>
    <Value>firstname surename</Value>
</list>
<list>
    <text1>contact</text1>
    <text2>post</text2>
    <text3>street</text3>
    <Value>mystreet</Value>
</list>
<list>
    <text1>contact</text1>
    <text2>post</text2>
    <text3>postalCode</text3>
    <Value>9876</Value>
</list>
<list>
    <text1>contact</text1>
    <text2>post</text2>
    <text3>city</text3>
    <Value>mycity</Value>
</list>
..........
...........
<list>
    <text1>contact</text1>
    <text2>othercontacts</text2>
    <text3>PHONE</text3>
    <Value>123456</Value>
</list>
<list>
    <text1>contact</text1>
    <text2>othercontacts</text2>
    <text3>FAX</text3>
    <Value>123457</Value>
</list>
    </MyList>
```

I have tried following but I have few problems:

1)-  I have tried to filter the outcome of “list” with "if" in such a way that only elements with values are transformed but I am also getting “list” elements which does not contain "text3" and "Value" elements. I have tried to delete them with empty template without any success.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
          <MyList>
          </xsl:for-each> 
          <xsl:for-each select="//data">
    <!-- selecting all nodes-->
              <xsl:for-each select="descendant::node()">
                  <list>
                       <text1><xsl:value-of select="name(parent::node())"/></text1>
                       <text2><xsl:value-of select="local-name(parent::node()[position()])"/></text2>

            <!-- tried to get only elements that does have a value of type text() -->
                       <xsl:if test="text() &gt;0" >
                       <text3><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/></text3>
                       <Value><xsl:value-of select="."/></Value>
                       </xsl:if>
                 </list>
                 </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each> 
          </MyList>
     </xsl:template>

<!-- tried to delete nodes that do not have element text3 -->
<xsl:template match="list[not(text3)]"/>           
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am looking forward for your reply. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is `report` not in your output XML? Why can `info` be a valid `text1` when its not under the root? Your logic is very ill-defined.

Comment: You are right my mistake in copy-past. I have edited the input XML.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense, as `info` isn't a root element but is made `text1` in your output. Don't edit the input XML if it has a `report` element in, nor should you change the Output XML if thats how you need it. *What is needed is a clearer explanation of the rules around the transform.* Perhaps the lack of clarity is why you haven't been able to answer your own question?

Comment: I will Review my Explanation. Maybe you could help me by asking some questions. Thanks anyway

Comment: I've added an updated answer based on your new criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (edited based on criteria in comments):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <MyList>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[text()!='']"/>
    </MyList>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[count(@type)=0]">
        <list>
            <xsl:variable name="p" select="count(ancestor::*)-1"/>
            <text1>
                <xsl:value-of select="name(ancestor::*[$p])"/>
            </text1>
            <text2>
                <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>
            </text2>
            <text3>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </text3>
            <Value>
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </Value>
        </list>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[count(@type)!=0]">
        <list>
            <xsl:variable name="p" select="count(ancestor::*)-1"/>
            <text1>
                <xsl:value-of select="name(ancestor::*[$p])"/>
            </text1>
            <text2>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </text2>
            <text3>
                <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
            </text3>
            <Value>
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </Value>
        </list>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And when applied to your input XML gives:

```
<MyList>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>reportId</text2>
        <text3>Number</text3>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>reportType</text2>
        <text3>code</text3>
        <Value>7</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>reportType</text2>
        <text3>text</text3>
        <Value>Main</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>product</text2>
        <text3>code</text3>
        <Value>3</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>product</text2>
        <text3>text</text3>
        <Value>myProduct</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>change</text2>
        <text3>code</text3>
        <Value>0</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>reportInfo</text2>
        <text3>language</text3>
        <Value>EN</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>reportInfo</text2>
        <text3>Date</text3>
        <Value>2013-09-25</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>requestInfo</text2>
        <text3>customerReference</text3>
        <Value>sample_Reference</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>requestType</text2>
        <text3>code</text3>
        <Value>53</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>requestType</text2>
        <text3>text</text3>
        <Value>Onlineanfrage</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>postBox</text2>
        <text3>postBoxNumber</text3>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>postBox</text2>
        <text3>postalCode</text3>
        <Value>123</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>postBox</text2>
        <text3>city</text3>
        <Value>abcd</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>postBox</text2>
        <text3>postBoxNumber</text3>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>postBox</text2>
        <text3>postalCode</text3>
        <Value>456</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>Info</text1>
        <text2>postBox</text2>
        <text3>city</text3>
        <Value>efgh</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>contact</text1>
        <text2>name</text2>
        <text3>fullname</text3>
        <Value>firstname surename</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>contact</text1>
        <text2>post</text2>
        <text3>street</text3>
        <Value>mystreet</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>contact</text1>
        <text2>post</text2>
        <text3>postalCode</text3>
        <Value>9876</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>contact</text1>
        <text2>post</text2>
        <text3>city</text3>
        <Value>mycity</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>contact</text1>
        <text2>country</text2>
        <text3>code</text3>
        <Value>110</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>contact</text1>
        <text2>country</text2>
        <text3>text</text3>
        <Value>mycountry</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>contact</text1>
        <text2>othercontacts</text2>
        <text3>PHONE</text3>
        <Value>123456</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>contact</text1>
        <text2>othercontacts</text2>
        <text3>FAX</text3>
        <Value>123457</Value>
    </list>
    <list>
        <text1>contact</text1>
        <text2>othercontacts</text2>
        <text3>EMAIL</text3>
        <Value>email@email.com</Value>
    </list>
</MyList>
```

Comment: Great; thank you very much Lego. I have still two Problems when I am running your solution. The most important 1) it is in _contact_. Here _othercontacts_ should be given in **text2** and _type_ of _othercontacts_ (e.g. "PHONE") should be copied in **text3**. Right now, it is not clear if the value is PHONE or FAX in this example. 2) I get still some elements unwanted “list” like:

Comment: `<Argument>
  <text1/>
  <text2/>
  <text3>data</text3>
  <Value>    </Value> `or `<Argument>
  <text1>Info</text1>
  <text2>Info</text2>
  <text3>reportInfo</text3>
  <Value>
                    </Value>`

Comment: @user2994176 I've made an edit based on the changed logic, **which is something you should have explained in the original question** and should edit in. This is exactly what I was talking about with regards to "ill-defined logic". Additionally, based on the XML you've given, I don't get the same behaviour as you regarding the 'empty' `text1` and `text2` elements

Comment: +1 for providing a good solution even if the question is _slightly_ confusing.

Comment: @Lego many thanks. I will try to give a beeter discription in my question next time.